# How to get list of values and not names of variables, in Autolisp

Tags: variables, lisp, evaluation, quote, autolisp

I am trying to create a function to use the variable name instead of values, but at the `princ` it is showing me only the name not the value.

```lisp
(defun c:loop3 ()
    (setq xp 5)
    (setq count 0)
    (setq zp 200)
    
    (setq yp 5)
    (setq cenPT '(count xp yp zp))
    (princ cenPT)
  (princ)
)
```

I am expecting to print the value `5 0 200` but it prints the name of the variables.

Answer (score 2):

The use of the apostrophe (`'`) or the quote function in AutoLISP causes the expression that follows to be marked as a literal expression, to be taken at face value and not interpreted - I explain this in far more detail in my tutorial on [The Apostrophe and the Quote Function](http://lee-mac.com/quote.html).

Hence, your expression:

```
(setq cenPT '(count xp yp zp))
```

Will result in the symbol `cenPT` being assigned the list of symbols `(COUNT XP YP ZP)` rather than evaluating such symbols to yield the values they may hold.

To evaluate the values, you should construct the list using the `list` function, i.e.:

```
(setq cenPT (list count xp yp zp))
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer

(setq cenPT count xp yp zp)

Comment: this has an odd number of arguments which is ill-defined, the purpose of the arguments in setq is to work in pair: set cenPT to count, set xp to yp, etc. but here it won't work because zp has no associated value

https://knowledge.autodesk.com/fr/support/autocad-for-mac/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/FRA/AutoCAD-MAC-Core/files/GUID-2F4B7A7B-7B6F-4E1C-B32E-677506094EAA-htm.html

Answer (score 0):

Just change
`(setq cenPT '(count xp yp zp))`
to
`(setq cenPT (list count xp yp zp))`